# Subdirectory in Gitlab not syncing

Tags: git, pycharm

One of the subdirectories in my GitLab project is not syncing.
What I mean by that:

- I commit & push.
- No errors occur. It shows as up to date in PyCharm.
- Nothing changes in this subdirectory in the remote GitLab project.

I think the problem is this: This directory was its own project some time ago but I now incorporated it into a bigger project. It seems like it wants to keep syncing with the old repo but this old repo does not exist anymore afaik. In "Manage Remotes" it still shows both projects, the main project and the former project of the subdirectory. I don't seem to be able to just remove the latter.

Also, what is weird about it, it worked for a couple of weeks without any problems and I cannot recall having changed anything.

I am pretty sure that is the problem but I do not find a way to change it to the correct remote repo. (I do not necessarily care about keeping the file history of this one subdirectory.)

Comment: Have you checked if there is a .git directory into the subdirectory ?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this was the directory that manages all the git related stuff. I also had to delete the old directory mapping.